# I have a problem running the Flutter project

Tags: image, flutter, debugging, caching, networking

hi have this error when I tryng to run my Flutter application [image: error running]
I'm beginner using Flutter, thank to your help.

There are my dependencies in the YAML file.

```
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
generic_bloc_provider: ^1.0.8
firebase_auth:
google_sign_in:
firebase_storage: ^2.1.0
cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13
image_picker: ^0.5.4+3
cached_network_image: ^0.8.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with **cached_network_image: ^0.8.0**

1. Try **flutter clean** in terminal window.
2. If the above does not solve the issue, then  try removing **cached_network_image: ^0.8.0** from pubspec.yaml and save pubspec.yaml. Run **flutter pub get** in terminal window Then add **cached_network_image: ^0.8.0** back again and run **flutter pub get** in terminal window.
3. If the above does not solve the issue, then  try to install a different version of the plugin, the current version is **cached_network_image: ^2.3.3**

I think the 3rd option should solve the issue. If not there is one more thing you can try.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried the 3 steps, but the 3rd solved the problem finally. Only shows a Notes about other dependency. Do you recomend update all the dependencies to the last versions?.

Comment: If you plan to do that then please do that one by one. Check everything works after every dependency is updated. Please proceed with extreme caution. Dependencies might have breaking changes, so be very careful. Do not do it if you are short on time or a deadline is near.